# Issu normalizing data ( entity with children of same entity )

Tags: normalizr

i'm very new to normalizr.

I'm trying to normalize a json api answer that looks like this: http://myjson.com/15st3f

There are some nested elements of same entity. For exemple:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "a",
  [...]
  "children": [
    "id": 2,
    "name": "b",
    [...]
    "children": [
      "id": 3,
      "name": "c"
    ]
  ]
}
```

How should I start this? I'm a bit confuse. Can it be normalized? Can you have array of same entity, or something like that ? Can I do something like this ? :

```
const uor = new schema.Entity('uors', {
    UorChildren: [ uor ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`define` instance method](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#instance-methods-1):

```
const uor = new schema.Entity('uors');
uor.define({ children: [ uor ] });
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. Found it in the API, under "instance methods", thanks to your comment.

https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#entitykey-definition---options--